# How to auto create foreingKey object (python with django)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a simple rest api

This is my actual result from devices, i create first the group and options, and then associate, but i want to create the options at the same time i create the device.

My result from devices right now

```
[
   
    {
        "id_device": "a099d2ce-812b-4d85-8c8b-cfe71057fbe7",
        "group": {
            "id_group": "39407ef6-1a3e-4965-9b61-96f6c40b76b3",
            "name": "Cozinha"
        },
        "options": [
            {
                "id_option": "1b383a37-5229-4ae0-9649-f76aa32eeda0",
                "name": "1",
                "identifier": "POWER1"
            },
            {
                "id_option": "4ff5406a-8c7b-4517-9ec0-14fd4f68f30b",
                "name": "2",
                "identifier": "POWER2"
            },
            {
                "id_option": "a541216d-f509-4461-85ca-444491ac9217",
                "name": "3",
                "identifier": "POWER3"
            },
            {
                "id_option": "3debe828-edd6-4d83-bfd8-2776a1594380",
                "name": "4",
                "identifier": "POWER4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Interruptor 4",
        "identifier": "identifiertest"
    },
]
```

my models.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

class Options(models.Model):
    id_option = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Groups(models.Model):
    id_group = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Devices(models.Model):
    id_device = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Options)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

viewsets

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from devices.api import serializers
from devices import models

class DevicesViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DevicesSerializer
    queryset = models.Devices.objects.all()
    
class OptionsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.OptionsSerializer
    queryset = models.Options.objects.all()

class GroupsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupsSerializer
    queryset = models.Groups.objects.all()
```

serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from devices import models


class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Options
        fields = '__all__'

class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Groups
        fields = '__all__'

class DevicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupsSerializer()
    options = OptionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Devices
        fields = '__all__'
```

I send this to create the device

```
{
    "group": {
        "name": "newgroup"
    },
    "options": [
        {    
           "name": "teste1",
           "identifier": "teste1" 
        }
     ],
    "name": "teste1",
    "identifier": "teste1"
}
```

but get this error:

> AssertionError at /devices/
> The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
> Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `devices.api.serializers.DevicesSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
> Request Method:   POST
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/devices/
> Django Version:   4.1.7
> Exception Type:   AssertionError
> Exception Value:
> The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
> Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `devices.api.serializers.DevicesSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

I know the response is here, but i dont know how to do it.
**I try some solutions from internet but none with success, so can someone help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**serializer.py**

```
class DevicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupsSerializer()
    options = OptionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Devices
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group_data = validated_data.pop('group')
        options_data = validated_data.pop('options')
        group, _ = models.Groups.objects.get_or_create(**group_data)
        options = [models.Options.objects.create(**option_data) for option_data in options_data]
        device = models.Devices.objects.create(group=group, **validated_data)
        device.options.set(options)
        return device
```

**viewsets.py:**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from devices.api import serializers
from devices import models

class DevicesViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DevicesSerializer
    queryset = models.Devices.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    
class OptionsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.OptionsSerializer
    queryset = models.Options.objects.all()

class GroupsViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupsSerializer
    queryset = models.Groups.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the answer is in there. Basically you have to provide a `def create(self, validated_data)` method to your `DevicesSerializer` class.

Here is something that could help:

```
class DevicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupsSerializer()
    options = OptionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Devices
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        options_data = validated_data.pop("options")
        device = models.Devices.objects.create(**validated_data)  # or you can manually pass the fields/data as kwargs

        for option_data in options_data:
            models.Options.objects.create(device=device, **option_data)

        return device
```

Basically, you need to manually save the base object (`Device`) and then manually iterate over the options data and create each of them pointing to the newly created `device`.

Comment: I try to use that but i get a error: Exception Value: 
type object 'Devices' has no attribute 'create'
Exception Location: C:\Users\rlima\Documents\smartHome\BE2\project\devices\api\serializers.py, line 25, in create

Comment: If i change create -> save, i get this error: Model.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'

Comment: This is my save json: {
   "group":{
      "id_group":"c18f7e57-9895-4b36-9d31-303b279d1d21",
      "name":"Cozinha"
   },
   "options":[
      {
         "name":"123",
         "identifier":"123"
      }
   ],
   "name":"123",
   "identifier":"123"
}

Comment: @Ricardo was missing `.objects` in the call hierarchy on the example.